# django admin send back to homepage

Tags: python, django

i am new to django and i am makeing my first site i tried to get on my admin for my site but when i go to 127.0.0.1/admin it sends me back to the home page i have look over my code multiple times and i just cant find anything wrong about it

here is my mysite urls

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
# this is mysite not main
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
#url('^admin/', admin.site.urls),
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', include('main.urls')),
    url('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),



]
```

here is my main.urls

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
# this is the main not mysite
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views


app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    url('',views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    url("register/", views.register,name='register'),


]





urlpatterns = [

    url("register/", views.register,name='register'),
    url('',views.homepage, name="homepage"),

]
```

this is my views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import cooking
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate


# Create your views here.



def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,template_name='main/home.html',context={"cooking": cooking.objects.all})

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,"main/register.html",context={"form":form })
```

please tell me if you need more info thankyou

Comment: would you mind to put here your project structure ? I am not sure which urls are from where

Comment: the main.urls comes from my main folder and the my site comes from my mysite folder they are both apps it all is in my mysite project folder

Comment: so the name of your project is `mysite` ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: edit in main homapage to this : `url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),`

Comment: it trew an error

Comment: in my hedder file

Comment: hmm ... in that case I am sorry, but I think you got me on this one :( ... good luck

Answer (score 0):

Change this `url('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls', ,namespace = "main"))` to your url mysite